# How to calculate unique daily and weekly launch date with date field only?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Sorry if this is worded poorly

I need to calculate the amount of sites that were launched by each day of the week. I currently only have the day something launches- which can be counted as 1 launch, and needs to be used for day of week.

I'm using bigquery so I have to use the extract function which I am new to.

```
SELECT
count(Distinct PUBLISHED_DAY),
EXTRACT(DAY from PUBLISHED_DAY) as dow
EXTRACT(WEEK(SUNDAY) from PUBLISHED_DAY) as sunday
EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY from PUBLISHED_DAY) as monday
EXTRACT(WEEK(TUESDAY) from PUBLISHED_DAY) as tuesday
EXTRACT(WEEK(WEDNESDAY) from PUBLISHED_DAY) as WEDNESDAY 
EXTRACT(WEEK(THURSDAY) from PUBLISHED_DAY) as THURSDAY
EXTRACT(WEEK(FRIDAY) from PUBLISHED_DAY) as FRIDAY
EXTRACT(WEEK(SATURDAY) from PUBLISHED_DAY) as Saturday 
FROM[table]
```

I'm getting this error and I also don't know think this will return the distinct days counted by day of week. 
 Error: Encountered " "FROM" "from "" at line 3, column 13. Was expecting: ")" ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM PUBLISHED_DAY) as dow, COUNT(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY dow;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using bigquery so I have to use the extract function which I am new to.

[EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract) function is available in BigQuery Standard SQL (not in Legacy SQL) which explains the error you see as you run it in Legacy SQL

So, just make sure you are rinnung your query in Standard SQL, for example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM PUBLISHED_DAY) AS dow,
  .... 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `FORMAT_DATE('%A', PUBLISHED_DAY)` instead of extract.